# Caption formatting with babel French

Tags: captions, babel, french

I have a problem override the default formatting of float captions when using babel’s French option. When babel’s `francais` setting is chosen, captions are formatted with the label (“Figure X”) in small caps. I'm trying to override that with the `caption` package, but to no avail. The following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\caption{xxxxx}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

where only the digit is italicized. If I comment out the `babel` line, it works correctly:

[image]

`caption`’s doc says that it should be loaded after `babel` to override it, but here it does not seem to be the case. Anyone knows how to work around this issue?

Comment: I suggest that you write the author of frenchb. http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/. It is imho a bad idea to put formatting instructions inside fix names like `\figurename`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package babel with the language `francais` loads the file `frenchb.ldf` with the following defintion:

```
\def\figurename{{\scshape Figure}}%
```

The combination of `\itshape\scshape` is defined with the current font so you will get the odd result.

I can't understand why babel influences the format.

However you have the following possibilities  to solve the issue:

**1. Usage of the package `caption`**

You can redefine the name via:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure}
```

**2. Usage of the package `babel`**

```
\addto\captionsfrancais{%
   \def\figurename{Figure}%
}
```

---

Here a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\addto\captionsfrancais{%
   \def\figurename{Figure}%
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=it,]{caption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\caption{xxxxx}\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem and found this solution in the babel manual:

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false}
```

Comment: +1 By the "babel manual" you mean `frenchb.pdf` in this case.